# Specify a character set for fontawesome-webfont.woff2

Tags: page-speed

I am looking to speed up my website as much as possible and am using gtmetrix. The last thing on the PageSpeed list that I have to complete is

Specify a character set early:

The following resources have no character set specified in their HTTP headers. Specifying a character set in HTTP headers can speed up browser rendering.

```
/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
```

I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: A quick fix would be to use a content delivery network that hosts the CSS library for you. There are many benefits on using a CDN such as MAX CDN or CDNJS, as these server files are already cached on by millions of users locally, therefore faster, also, those who don't have it cached will receive the file super quick due to CDN technology. See [Font Awesome's own getting started CDN](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) or [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome).

Answer (score 1):

Your Content-Type is likely set wrong.   When the content type is a text content type, you should also specify a character set:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

You may have the content type set to text for your `.woff` files and it is complaining that there is no character set.   It is complaining about the wrong thing.   Really should you have your [content type for woff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts) set like:

```
Content-Type: application/x-font-woff
```

With an `application` content type, there is no need for a character set.   Once that is in place, the warning should go away.